# ListView: How to set nextFocusDown to an element in the next row?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a `ListView` with two `EditText` in each row:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/trainingDetailCol1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/trainingDetailCol2"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:digits="0123456789.,"/>
<EditText
        android:id="@id/trainingDetailCol2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:digits="0123456789.,"/>
```

Is there a way to receive focus on `trainingDetailCol1`, but in the next row? So it goes EditText1-Row1 -> EditText2-Row1 -> EditText1-Row2 and so on. Right now by adding a `android:nextFocus...` to the second `EditText` the focus will jump to EditText2 in row 2

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What I did was to set an OnKeyListener on the EditText and listen for the KeyCode_Enter.

If it got clicked i looked watched out for the EditText that should receive the focus and gave it to it. In my case it looked something like this

```
int childRowCount = this.rootLayout.getChildCount();
for (int i = 0; i < childRowCount; i++) {
    LinearLayout rootLayout = (LinearLayout) this.rootView.findViewById(R.id.root);
    LinearLayout row = (LinearLayout) rootLayout.getChildAt(i);
    EditText et = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.some_et);
    et.setTag(i); // -> i save the row in which i am in a tag
    et.setOnKeyListener(this);
}
```

And in the Listener I do

```
@Override
public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
        try {
            Integer tag = (Integer) view.getTag();
            LinearLayout rowX = (LinearLayout) this.rootLayout.getChildAt(tag + 1);
            EditText nextET = (EditText)rowX.findViewById(R.id.next);
            fakeEditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            fakeEditText.requestFocus();
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            // do nothing
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The first step is to save the index of the row (the row is a layout) in the rows tag. You can do this in your getView() if you like. Second step is to read what index got clicked and set the focus to the row with index + 1

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin.

In the ListViewAdapter class, fun getView(), add lastEditText.setOnKeyListner as below:

```
    lastEditText.setOnKeyListener { v, keyCode, event ->
    var setOnKeyListener = false
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        try {
            val nextRow = getViewByPosition(position + 1, parent as ListView) as LinearLayout
            val nextET = nextRow.findViewById(R.id.firstEditText) as EditText
            nextET.isFocusableInTouchMode = true
            nextET.requestFocus()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // do nothing
        }
        setOnKeyListener = true
    }
    setOnKeyListener
}
```

add the fun getViewByPosition() after fun getView() as below:

```
    private fun getViewByPosition(pos: Int, listView: ListView): View? {
    val firstListItemPosition: Int = listView.firstVisiblePosition
    val lastListItemPosition: Int = firstListItemPosition + listView.childCount - 1
    return if (pos < firstListItemPosition || pos > lastListItemPosition) {
        listView.adapter.getView(pos, null, listView)
    } else {
        val childIndex = pos + listView.headerViewsCount - firstListItemPosition
        listView.getChildAt(childIndex)
    }
}
```